# Conditional not working as expected

Tags: conditionals

I have this code

```
{exp:low_replace find="\r|\n|\t" replace="" regex="yes"}
    {if '{member_group}' == 7}
        aaa
    {if:else}
        zzz
    {/if}
    {if '{logged_in_member_group}' != 7}
        bb
    {if:else}
        yyy
    {/if}
    {if {logged_in_member_group} == '7'}
        ccc
    {if:else}
        xxx
    {/if}
    {if {logged_in_member_group} != '7'}
        dddd
    {if:else}
        www
    {/if}
    {member_group}
{/exp:low_replace}
```

The output is

`zzz yyy xxx www 7`

This is weird because the output of `{member_group}` is 7.

Why are the conditionals not matching?

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out? If so, it is helpful if you mark an answer correct.

Answer (score 6):

Member defined variables like `{member_group}` are **parsed last** by default, so your advanced (not simple) conditionals will never properly read the member data. [View parse order pdf by Low](http://loweblog.com/downloads/ee-parse-order.pdf).

You need to install an add-on to move the parsing of the member defined variables earlier. Try Low Variables, Mo' Variables, or any other add-on that has this feature.

Comment: I've made a small extension just for member vars for this http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/global-member-vars

Answer (score 6):

First off, you can't have any "else" statements in your conditional or it will be considered "advanced".

But more importantly in relation to how you're writing these: Simple Conditionals aren't just about the operators, control structures & variables, but the *format* is actually critical.

The actual format must be:

```
{if early_parsed_variable == "string"}
...
{/if}
```

Basically the left-hand side **must NOT** have curly brackets or quotes; and the right-hand side **MUST** have quotes.  This is the exact and only pattern that EE looks for when trying to hunt down a Simple Conditional - along with the other requirements.

It's bewildering I know - it promted me to write a post about all the times you might think you've written a Simple Condition, but haven't:

http://johndwells.com/blog/when-a-simple-conditional-isnt